# How to make rsync copy the contents of symbolic link FILES but only copy the symlink file for directories?

Tags: rsync, backup, symlink

I found that I can use the `-L` option to copy the contents of all symbolic links, including directories. However, I need only to copy the referent **files** pointed to by symbolic links, and copying entire directories is a bad use of storage space.

I have found `-K`/`--keep-dirlinks` which seemed promising, but it actually seems to do the opposite of what I wanted and copies the full directories just like `-L`.

I see `-H` ("preserve hard links") in the manual, but my links are symbolic links, not hard links, so I do not think that would work.

Thank you for any help you can offer me!